# Why does VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR cause catastrophic performance issues in Ubuntu MATE?

Tags: graphics, desktop, frame-rate, vulkan

I am implementing a simple Vulkan renderer according to a popular Vulkan tutorial (https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction), and I've run into an interesting issue with the presentation mode and the desktop environment performance.

I wrote the triangle demo on Windows, and it performed well; however, I ported it to my Ubuntu installation (running MATE 1.20.1) and discovered a curious problem with the performance of the entire desktop environment while running it; certain swapchain presentation modes seem to wreak utter havoc with the desktop environment.

When setting up a Vulkan swapchain with `presentMode` set to `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` and subsequently running the application, the entire desktop environment grinds to a halt whenever *any* window is dragged. When literally any window on the entire desktop is dragged, the entire desktop environment slows to a crawl, appearing to run at roughly 4-5 fps. However, when I replace the `presentMode` with `VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR`, the desktop environment is immune to this issue and does not suffer the performance issues when dragging windows.

When I researched this before asking here, I saw that several people discovered that they experienced this behavior when their application was delivering frames as fast as possible (not vsync'd), and that properly synchronizing with vsync resolved this stuttering. However, in my case, it's the opposite; when I use `VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR`, i.e., not waiting for vsync, the dragging performance is smooth, and when I synchronize with vsync with `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR`, it stutters.

`VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_RELAXED_KHR` produces identical (catastrophic) results as the standard FIFO mode.

I tried using the Compton GPU compositor instead of Compiz; the effect was still there (regardless of what window was being dragged, the desktop still became extremely slow) but was slightly less pronounced than when using Compiz.

I have fully implemented the `VkSemaphore`-based frame/image/swapchain synchronization scheme as defined in the tutorial, and I verified that while using `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` the application is only rendering frames at the target 60 frames per second. (When using `IMMEDIATE`, it runs at 7,700 fps.)

**Most interestingly,** when I measured the frametimes (using `glfwGetTime()`), during the periods when the window is being dragged, the frametime is *extremely* short. The screenshot shows this; you can see the extremely short/abnormal frame time when a window is being dragged, and then the "typical" frametime (locked to 60fps) while the window is still.

[image: screenshot]

In addition, *only while using `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR`*, while this extreme performance degradation is being observed, `Xorg` pegs the CPU to 100% on one core, while the running Vulkan application uses a significant amount of CPU time as well (73%) as shown in the screenshot below. This spike is only observed while dragging windows in the desktop environment, and is not observed at all if `VK_PRESENT_MODE_IMMEDIATE_KHR` is used.

[image]

I am curious if anyone else has experienced this and if there is a known fix for this window behavior.

System info: Ubuntu 18.04, Mate 1.20.1 w/ Compiz, Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Edit: [This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/cpjzmt/psa_for_anyone_having_intermittent_hangups_on/ewq0ori/) seems to have a similar description of an issue; the `VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR` causing extreme desktop performance issues under Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Edit 2: **This bug can be easily reproduced using `vkcube` from `vulkan-tools`.** Compare the desktop performance of `vkcube` using `--present-mode 0` vs `--present-mode 2`.

Comment: I had a the same kind of problem using the `amdvlk` drivers on Arch: the display would stutter a ~5 Hz even with very small measured frame times on some present modes with a certain compute load and on all present modes with a different compute load. Switching to `vulkan-radeon` solved the issue for me. I don't think there are alternative Nvidia drivers available though.

Comment: Thanks @Tau for the followup... Vulkan driver support on Linux sure seems like it has a ways to go, w.r.t. stuttering.